# Where should utility functions in a Firefox Extension be placed

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

As I'm writing a Firefox XUL Extension I find that I want to share some functionality (the business logic) across the whole extension. What would be the best place to store this?

Can I create some sort of library (javascript) file which always gets loaded first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely want to create a [JavaScript code module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules). You can use [Components.utils.import()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.import) to load it:

```js
Components.utils.import("chrome://myaddon/content/utils.jsm");
```

And in `utils.jsm` you define which symbols should be imported by that statement, e.g.:

```js
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["Utils"];

var Utils = {
};
```

The module will be loaded when it is first used and stay in memory after that - there will be only a single module instance no matter how many places on your extension use it. Note that I used a `chrome://` URL to load the module, this is supported starting with Firefox 4. Documentation recommends using `resource://` URLs which is cleaner because modules don't actually have anything to do with the user interface - still, using a `chrome://` URL is often simpler.